# Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal During DevOps Implementation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have tried to deploy an Azure Data Factory ARM template into an instance using DevOps.

To deploy there are three steps.

1. Stop the trigger with pre deployment scripts provided by microsoft.
2. ARM template deployment
3. Post deployment scripts by microsoft to refresh resources and restart trigger.

pre and post deployment script available from below microsoft link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

[image]

But while running the task I am getting below error.
[image]

I did a debug and find out that might be the issue with service connection in the DevOps project settings.

The above issue was because of service connection from devops project. It was resolved when I create a new service connection.

Comment: Are you running the job on a self-hosted agent? As far as I know, the Managed Identity option only works if it is your own agent with Managed Identity configured on it.

Comment: Selected agent from Azure Pipeline, Think it is Microsoft hosted one.

Comment: " But while running the task I am getting below error." What's the first error task in your pipeline? Looks like a powershell task which you mentioned `Stop the trigger with pre deployment scripts.`  Are you using your own script to handle this. Are you able to deploy an Azure Data Factory ARM template   locally instead through Azure DevOps.

Comment: First task is to stop the trigger with pre deployment scripts provided by data factory. I am able to do a custom deployment through azure portal

Comment: Hi @Antony Sorry for not make it more clearly. We could not create test pipeline with this "Azure Data Factory ARM template" by default either through Classic UI or YAML. Could you share the screenshot of your related task setting  or YAML code. ?

Comment: I have used the pre and post deployment scripts provided at the end of page by microsoft. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/… The above issue was resolved when I create a new Service Connection from DevOps project settings.

Answer (score 3):

The above issue was because of service connection from devops project when I try to create a connection to the ADF instance using Managed Identity as Authentication method. It was resolved when I create a new service connection with Authentication method as Service Principal.